# python OOP vs dict

Tags: python, oop

I am new to Python and OOP. For some reason I have some troubles to understand OOP  and not sure when to use class (objects) and when dictionaries.

I have a file in following format:

```
system1 attr1 attr2 attr3
system2 attr1 attr2 attr3
system3 attr1 attr2 attr3
system4 attr1 attr2 attr3
```

...

Any advice how to create a class where my objecs will be items in 1st column and propertiers/attributes in 2-4 columns? T

I am able to do this with dict but not sure how to use class here?
Any guidlelines pls?

ZDZ

Comment: Can you post the code for how you did this with `dict`s?

Comment: Usually one uses a classes if the fields are more or less fixed: i.e. all objects have exactly the same fields. Furthermore OO is used if these fields have a semantical meaning, or reference each other in a circular way. Dictionaries are usually used if the keys are more arbitrary (i.e. the names of students). Note that most classes use under the hood a dictionary, and that Python adds some magic to it.

Comment: Damn, I can't remember where the quote came from, but some Python programmers mockingly make a sport of having colleagues defend their self written classes when they could just have used a dictionary plus some extra methods.

Comment: So do you want an object which represents `system1 attr1 attr2 attr3`, or do you want an object which is `system1`, or do you want an object which has the attributes `attr1 attr2 attr3`?

Comment: You should probably use *both* for this particular example. The data should be stored in a `dict`, and held internally within a manager class. The class would be responsible for reading and writing the data, and provide accessor methods for the data. So the overall structure would be a simplified version of something like the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) class in the stdlib.

Comment: @smac89, i want object that has attr1-3!

Comment: @Scott Hunter,  system = {}, I open the file and then create dicts system[k[0]] = k[1:]

Comment: If you have a large number of systems and/or attributes, and if you are looking to do any kind of data analysis, I would recommend Pandas as a container. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, classes are best used when they have to do something; this is when you define methods/functions for them. 
if you're just wanting to store the data then using dictionaries is fine.

```
d = {}
d['system1'] = {}
d['system1']['attr1'] = value_of_attr1
```

i use multidimensional dicts in a lot of my code to keep it organized. unless there is something to be done, i stick with dicts.

Comment: Cheers Taylor. I am ok with dict and i used the very same structure.